# Difficulty Centering Pictures

Tags: css, html

I am having problems centering two pictures on a page:

```
<div name="pics"style="text-align:center;padding:70px">
<a name="picofday"><img class="picofday" src="castle.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a name="frame"><img class="frame" src="frame.png" width="50%" height="50%" alt=""/>     
</a>
</div>
```

I have tried adding a text-align attribute and centering the pictures in CSS:

```
frame{display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
.picofday{
display: block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: each image on a row ?? or both aside and center?

Comment: Did you mean `frame`, or `.frame`, for your selector? Is this your actual issue, or a typo when transferring code to SO? Also, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaVH3/) of current code, with images replaced by 75px by 75px http://placehold.it/ image.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
a {
    display: block;
}
a img {
    dsiplay: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There could be a few reasons why your elements didn't center. First try adding `margin: 0px` auto to your element.

For margin: 0 auto; to work, an element needs to have a set width like `width: 100px;`.
If the element has a set width and still does't center, try display: block;.
Those two things will always work.

How to center elements without `margin: 0 auto;`:

If you're just trying to center all elements inside the body tag, just use `text-align: center;` on the body tag to accomplish that.

That said, I don't think you were trying to do that though.

Answer (score -1):

make your A tags display to block and set margin to 0px auto;
it will justify the elements